# How do I find the maximum profit?

Tags: calculus, optimization

How do I find max profit if I am only given a cost function and how much the item sells for?
$$C(X)=x{^3}-60{x^2}+1400x+1000$$
Product sells for $\$563$ per unit.

I am also given $0\leq x \leq 50$. No demand or supply function has been given. Only cost. I have already tried taking the derivative, dividing by $x$ to get the average.

I attempted to take the derivative of the cost function but then noticed its a cost function not revenue, so thats out of the bat. I also attempted to take Cbar and try to get average but then saw it asked for profit then I got confused and decided to ask for help.

Comment: You don't give us the functions.  What function did you take the derivative of?  Why did you then divide this by $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please write out ALL the information, using mathjax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help you do so, and then we stand a better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Hint: If an item sells for $C$ units of currency, and you sell $n$ of them, what is the revenue?

Comment: Look up the definition of cost function in your textbook. Usually it is total cost of production, not cost per unit. On the other hand you've been given a fixed price per unit, from which you can deduce a revenue function.

Answer (score 2):

Profit = Income - Cost

It costs $C(x) = x^3 - 60x^2 + 1400x + 1000$ to make $x$ items, and you earn $I(x) = 563x$ for selling $x$ items. Subtracting these, we get:

Profit: $P(x) = -x^3 + 60x^2 - 837x - 1000$
To maximize profit, we need to find where the derivative is zero.

$P'(x) = -3x^2 + 120x - 837$

This function has zeroes at $9$ and $31$. Which should we use?
The second derivative test helps identify max and min.

$P''(x) = -6x + 120$
$P''(9) > 0$, so $9$ is a minimum.
$P'(31) < 0$, so $31$ is a maximum.

$P(31) = \$922$